# How to stop my div from overlapping?

Tags: html, css

I am just a beginner in HTML/CSS 
How to stop the floating div from overlapping.

[jsfiddle-link](https://jsfiddle.net/2Lk13045/)

HTML

```
<body>
  <div class="left">

  </div>
  <div class="right">

  </div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  width: 100%;
}

.left {
  float: left;
  height: 500px;
  width: 300px;
  background: #fff;
  position: absolute;
}

.right {
  float: right;
  height: 500px;
  width: 300px;
  background: #000;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use widths in percentages and remove the absolute positions:

Here is the updated CSS:

```
*{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;

}
body{
  width:100%;
}
.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
}
.left{
  float:left;
  height:500px;
  width:50%;
  background:#fff;
}
.right{
  float:right;
   height:500px;
  width:50%;
  background:#000;
}
```

I have also wrapped `left` and `right` divs in a `wrapper` div
Check it here: https://jsfiddle.net/2Lk13045/2/

Answer (score 0):

You set your width fixed instead of 100%.

https://jsfiddle.net/2Lk13045/1/]

Changed your

```
body{width:100%; }
```

to

```
body{width:600px; }
```